# Correct query using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables "Users" and "UserType". There is a relationship between these tables on "userTypeID" column. This column is primary key in the "UserType" table and foreign key in the "User" table. I also have a property in "User" class like follows:

```
public virtual UserType usertype{ get; set; }
```

I am querying "User" table like follows:

```
List<MyApp.Entity.Models.User> userList = new List<User>();
using (var DBContext = new UserDBContext())
{
userList  = DBContext.User.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).OrderBy(i => i.userName).ToList();
return userList;
}
```

When I am debugging the code, userList.usertype is null. I need to have the UserType in the userList. What am I doing wrong? I am new to Entity Framework.

Comment: You don't need to in initialize `userList`.You context returns that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include at the top of your class:

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

Then modify your query like so:

```
userList  = DBContext.User
                .Include(u => u.usertype)
                .Where(x => x.IsActive)
                .OrderBy(i => i.userName)
                .ToList();
```

This is called `Eager Loading`. You can read more about it here:  [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm, what you do is Eager, not Lazy loading.

Comment: Lazy loading is making additional queries to load related entities

Comment: And Lazy loading is no more available as soon as you dispose your context (as you do with your using clause)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've changed my answer to state that its Eager loading, not Lazy Loading :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly include your `usertype`.

```
userList  = DBContext.User
.Include("usertype")
.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).OrderBy(i => i.userName).ToList();
```

Or with lambda:
Add `using System.Data.Entity;`

```
userList  = DBContext.User
.Include(x => x.usertype)
.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).OrderBy(i => i.userName).ToList();
```